# xhtml/mobile 1.2 DOCTYPE is causing weird artifacts

Tags: html, css, video, dtd

I've the following HTML

```
<html> 
<body> 
<div style="background:white;width:620px; height: 464px; overflow: hidden;">
<style>.v{width:100%;background: red;border:0px; color:#FFFFFF;text-align: 
center; font-size: 11px;font-family:arial; vertical-align: middle;}</style>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/">
<div style="height:28px;width:620px;display:table-cell" class="v">Video</div>
</a><video style="background:black" height="408px" width="100%" ></video>
<a target="_blank" >
<div class="v" style="height:28px;width:620px;display:table-cell">Bottom</div></a></div>
```

When I use a DOCTYPE with this I get a white line below the Video, otherwise it renders fine. This is without DOCTYPE.[image]
And this is with doctype `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">`[image]
I tried tweaking CSS, but with no luck. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "display:block" or "vertical-align:bottom" to the css of your video element.